# Kafka with mqtt source and jdbc sink

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a kafka and use as a source a MQTT broker, the json where define this is,

```
{
"name": "mqtt-source",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": 1,
    "mqtt.server.uri": "tcp://localhost:1883",
    "mqtt.topics":"shellies/+/emeter/+/power", 
    "mqtt.username": "test",
    "mqtt.password": "testPass",
    "kafka.topic": "mqtt_messages",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "confluent.topic.replication.factor": 1
}
```

}

When I run the command

```
 docker exec -it kafka ./bin/kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --topic mqtt_messages
```

I can see the messages like this,

```
shellies/shellyem-M/emeter/0/power  51.70
shellies/shellyem-M/emeter/1/power  0.00
shellies/shellyem-M/emeter/0/power  54.20
shellies/shellyem-M/emeter/1/power  0.00
```

Then I want use jdbc sink to store these messages to postgres in table power_metrics, which has three fields.The topic(string) where I want to save the key of message, the time(timestamp) the time and value(float) the value of the message. And use this json,

```
{
  "name": "jdbc-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": 1,
    "topics": "mqtt_messages",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://timescaledb:5432/metrics",
    "connection.user": "postgres",
    "connection.password": "password",
    "auto.create": true,
    "auto.evolve": true,
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "pk.fields": "topic",
    "table.name.format": "power_metrics",
    "fields.whitelist": "topic,value",
    "transforms": "InsertField,ConvertTimestamp",
    "transforms.InsertField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
    "transforms.InsertField.static.field": "topic",
    "transforms.InsertField.static.value": "sample_topic_value",
    "transforms.ConvertTimestamp.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
    "transforms.ConvertTimestamp.field": "time",
    "transforms.ConvertTimestamp.format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
    "transforms.ConvertTimestamp.target.type": "Timestamp",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter"
  }
}
```

and I get this error for sink connector,

```
    org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value null for configuration static.value: No value specified for static field: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$InsertionSpec@1108a1c5
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig.transformations(ConnectorConfig.java:264)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.buildWorkerTask(Worker.java:528)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startTask(Worker.java:465)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startTask(DistributedHerder.java:1147)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.access$1600(DistributedHerder.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$12.call(DistributedHerder.java:1162)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$12.call(DistributedHerder.java:1158)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value null for configuration static.value: No value specified for static field: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$InsertionSpec@1108a1c5
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField.configure(InsertField.java:122)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig.transformations(ConnectorConfig.java:261)
    ... 10 more
```

Any idea how can I sovle this?

Answer (score 0):

First off, JDBC Sink requires a schema.

If you want to consume and store JSON as TEXT in the database rather than BLOB, you need to use JSONConverter. When you use ByteArrayConverter, there are no fields to manipulate for transforms.

In order to use either transform that modifies/inserts value fields, you'll need to add HoistField transform for the value.

You also need two InsertField transforms to add record timestamp as well as topic name, one using `timestamp.field`, and the other using `topic.field`, not `static.value`

I suggest you debug the output first using Filesink connector